# JSONPath and json4s

Tags: json, scala, jsonpath, json4s

I need to extract a field value from the message:

```
{
  "data": {
    "code": "404",
    ...
  }
}
```

JSONPath expression is stored in a variable:

```
val path = "/data/code"
```

I'm using [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) for manipulating JSON.

From the doc, one can achieve this using DSL:

```
val json = parse(message)
val code = json \ "data" \ "code"
```

It works, but obviously the JSONPath expression should be hardcoded.
Is there any way to evaluate expression stored as string? 
Something like:

```
val code = json.evaluateJSONPath(path)
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming the json path is provided in a string format delimited by comma the below would work.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
val json = parse(""" { "data": { "code": "404", "foo": "bar" } } """)
val path = "data,code" // json path in string 
path.split(',').foldLeft(json)({ case (acc, node) => acc \ node })
```

**Edit**:
Adding a implicit class to simplify the access

```
implicit class JsonHelper(json: JValue) {
    def customExtract[T](path: String)(implicit formats: Formats, mf: Manifest[T]) = {
        path.split(',').foldLeft(json)({ case (acc: JValue, node: String) => acc \ node }).extract[T]
    }
}

json.customExtract[String]("data,code")
res23: String = "404"
```

Comment: Thanks. But I hope something more concise will be proposed.

Comment: sure. I have updated the answer with a implicit class to simplify the access.

Answer (score 0):

How about use the **high order function** to map the **extract command**, like:

```
val extractCodeFunc = (j: JValue) => j \ "data" \ "code"
```

and extract `json`:

```
val res = extractCodeFunc.apply(json)
```

Comment: I prefer to avoid hardcoding the path.